# Creating new types in C++

Tags: c++, typedef

Using typedef in C++ creates an alias for a type.

So:

```
typedef double Length;
typedef double Mass;
```

creates two aliases which can be intermixed. In other words we can pass a value of type Mass to a function that expects a value of type Length.

Is there a lightweight way of creating new types? I would like them to be double underneath but be "different" so that one can't be used in place of another.

I would prefer something lighter than creating a new class or struct. Also, I am aware of the dimensions lib in boost. This is more complex and does a lot more than I need.

Comment: If you're into C++-like languages, D's `typedef` is strong, and its `alias` is equivalent to the weak `typedef` of C++. I think `typedef` is deprecated in D2, unfortunately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a new primitive type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572420/creating-a-new-primitive-type)

Comment: Not a duplicate: that one specifically asked for implicit conversions, and this question specifically doesn't want them. ("can't be used in place of another").

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) seems to be designed exactly for what you're looking for. I believe it does it's magic by creating a class and overloading the operators to make it behave like a builtin type, but I've not looked at it's implementation.

Comment: Ah, I was just going to type out something like that. Once again Boost already has the solution for problems I hadn't even made up :-) I wish C++11 had introduces `explicit typedef`s, though...

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/strong_typedef.hpp It is basically a macro which generates a customized class. You can easily copy that idea and reuse it in your own code.

Comment: +1: true! And yes, it's based on a struct, but uses boost::operators, so a non-boost version would be quite bloated.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion it is solved by template metaprogramming.

Comment: @vsz: How so? I don't see any TMP going on there.

Comment: I never used BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF, this (overly exaggerated) suspicion was only based on some interesting Boost solutions to generate compiler errors/warnings in similar cases. TMP was used to generate custom compiler errors/warnings if the types would have been accepted by C++ but were intended to be "different".

Comment: @vsz: I don't see that in the implementation.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: `explicit typedef` would be great, indeed - much like Haskell's awesome `newtype`.

Answer (score 11):

While BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF is a pretty simple solution, if you're mixing lengths and masses into more complicated units (e.g. in the physical sciences) then you might want to use [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_units.html).

Answer (score 4):

One other possible answer in C++11 is to use enum class : type. This will allow you to do what you want but it has its own downsides. For example you would have to overload a lot of operators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum class A : int; 
enum class B : int;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& t){
    os << static_cast<int>(t);
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const B& t){
    os << static_cast<int>(t);
    return os;
}

int test(A t){
    std::cout << "A " << t << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int test(B t){
    std::cout << "B " << t << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    A a{static_cast<A>(42)};
    B b{static_cast<B>(0)};

    test(a);
    test(b);
}
```

This would give the output of:

```
A 42
B 0
```

Or you could just get the integer part like this

```
template<class T>
int GetInt(T t)
{
    return static_cast<int>(t);    
}

std::cout << "B " << GetInt(t) << std::endl;
```

Comment: only good answer on here. No one should ever use boost and c++20... well...

Answer (score 2):

If the Metaclasses proposal (p7070) goes through (right now it's still at [revision0](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0707r0.pdf)), then we shall be able to create strong typedefs using an empty metaclass. Proposed syntax:

```
$class strong_typedef { };
using Length = $double.as(strong_typedef);
using Mass = $double.as(strong_typedef);
```

Earliest we might see this would be C++20