# Comparing same types with different names

Tags: c++

I've got

```
typedef void* TA;
typedef void* TB;
```

I need to compare names of types as different types.
There are `std::is_same<TA, TB>::value` and `typeid(TA)==typeid(TB)` return *true*, but I need *false*.

Comment: That won't work because you can just replace `TA` with `void*` anywhere you use it. A `typedef` does not create a new type, it only creates an alias

Comment: `typedef` and `using` don't define new types, they create aliases. `TA` and `TB` are the same type. To create a new type you need `struct` or `class` (or I guess `union`). For example `struct TA { void * ptr; };`.

Comment: fyi or duplicate (not sure) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512925/strong-typedef-for-primitive-types-boost-strong-typedef-is-not-cutting-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible because they are the same type.

If you are trying to use these as opaque handles with strong type-checking, another thing you can do is to forward-declare the classes in a header, and define them in your implementation file:

```
// ta_tb.hpp

typedef struct ta_impl* TA;
typedef struct tb_impl* TB;
```

Later:

```
// ta_tb.cpp

struct ta_impl { /* ... */ };
struct tb_impl { /* ... */ };
```

This enables type-checking for the handles, but doesn't leak the implementation details.