# C++ - "HARD" types

Tags: c++, c++17, strong-typedef

Is there a solution to force a type in case the type itself is an alias?

Example:

```
using my_type = uint32_t;
void my_function(my_type type) { ... }
```

In the example above, valid code is both **A and B**:

**A: proper implementation**

```
int main() 
{
  my_type type = 0;
  my_function(type);
  return 0;
}
```

**B: valid but improper implementation**

```
int main() 
{
  uint32_t type = 0; // <--- true type instead of alias
  my_function(type);
  return 0;
}
```

is there a way i could force a compiler error (GCC) if the true-type is used instead of the alias?
in the example of enums, in C++ i typically "force" it by using "enum class" rather than "enum".

im looking for a similar solution.

*Note:*

Of course in this case it's questionable if this even makes sense. I used a super simplified code example above to demonstrate my question. In my actual use case its important to have such a solution.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, it's an alias so basically you can use them interchangeably.

Comment: No there is not. You can create a distinct type that has all the same operations as an `uint32_t`. In fact I'd be surprised if there isn't a library somewhere where that has already been done.

Comment: I suppose the further question is whether you are ever going to want two integer like types, which are not only distinct from integers, but also distinct from each other. Seems like a bit of a rabbit hole to me.

Comment: It may be possible to achieve something similar to what you want with a configurable linter. I wonder if clang-tidy or semgrep can do something like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512925/strong-typedef-for-primitive-types-boost-strong-typedef-is-not-cutting-it

Comment: Just for what it's worth, Ada does provide this. Its equivalent of a C++ typedef/using is something like `type foo is bar;`, but it also has `type foo is new bar`, which makes `foo` a type that acts like a `bar`, but doesn't allow you to substitute a `bar` where a `foo` is required.

Comment: No.   A type alias (whether created using a `typedef` or a `using` declaration) is an alias for a type.  So, given `using my_type = uint32_t;`  (if `uint32_t` is previously declared as a type) a `my_type` and `uint32_t` are alternative names for exactly the same type, and there is no distinction between them.    You might try creating a distinct `struct` or `class` type that *contains* a `uint32_t`, and pass that around (as long as there is not an implicit conversion of a `uint32_t` to/from that `struct`/`class` type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't anything simple for this in the language.

The usual approach is to define `my_type` as a class type with `uint32_t` as only member and overloading the operators so that `my_type` behaves like a `uint32_t` (potentially with restrictions).

This concept is called "*strong types*" and it probably makes sense to use a library that implements them generically as templates.

Answer (score 3):

To make the idea in the other answer more concrete: you can make a class with an `explicit` constructor:

```
struct my_int32_t
{
    explicit my_int32_t(int32_t v): v(v) {}
    int32_t v;
};
```

This way, `my_function(3)` will be an error, like you want it to be. To make an object of this type requires "constructor syntax": `my_int32_t value(3)` or `my_int32_t value{3}`. The syntax `my_int32_t value = 3` will not work. You may consider this a feature of this "strong typing" implementation.