# use typedef for more type safe in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to revisit the [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/243154/c-strongly-typed-typedef). Currently, I am trying to avoid bug created by mixing Rad and Degree types for angles in my program.

For example:

```
  typedef float Degree;
  typedef float Radian;

  Degree a = 15.;

  Radian b = 3.14/4.;

  float c = a + b;  // no compile error
```

is there new update solution for this?

EDIT 01:

I resort to write my own class with hope for its small size and no dependency. Here's the working code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

template<typename numT>
class RadAngle {
public:
    RadAngle() {
      AngVal = 0.0;
    }
    RadAngle(const numT& angV) {
      AngVal = angV;
    }
    void operator = (const RadAngle<numT>& ang1) {
      AngVal = ang1.getVal();
    }
    RadAngle operator+(const RadAngle<numT>& ang1) const { return RadAngle<numT>(AngVal+ang1.getVal()); }
    RadAngle operator-(const RadAngle<numT>& ang1) const { return RadAngle<numT>(AngVal-ang1.getVal()); }
    RadAngle operator*(const RadAngle<numT>& ang1) const { return RadAngle<numT>(AngVal*ang1.getVal()); }
    RadAngle operator/(const RadAngle<numT>& ang1) const { return RadAngle<numT>(AngVal/ang1.getVal()); }

    numT getVal() const { return AngVal;};

private:
    numT AngVal;
};


int main() {

   RadAngle<float> a(1.5);
   RadAngle<float> b(3.14);
   RadAngle<float> c = a+b;

   //std::cout << c << std::endl;
//    printf("%.2f",c.getVal());


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: perhaps writing classes Degree and Radian might solve but the additional work on writing the operators might be cumbersome I guess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a new primitive type using C++11 style strong typedefs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726038/how-can-i-create-a-new-primitive-type-using-c11-style-strong-typedefs)

Comment: looks like this is a not proper question to ask? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726038/how-can-i-create-a-new-primitive-type-using-c11-style-strong-typedefs

Comment: so there's probably no way around to resolve this? the last post was in 2014. I am hoping to remove the bug from my code with this type safe feature

Comment: How about [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have doesn't help type safety at all, except perhaps as weak documentation. As far as the compiler is concerned, `float`, `Degree`, and `Radian` are complete synonyms; this is called a weak type alias. Strong type aliases are not a part of C++, but you can work around that. Two good articles on that are [here](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/23/strong-types-inheriting-functionalities-from-underlying/) and [here](http://foonathan.net/blog/2016/10/19/strong-typedefs.html). The basic idea is to create a generic class template for a strong typedef, and use that to create each individual alias.

If you don't want to write all the boilerplate yourself even once, I recommend using a third-party library to handle this. Both the authors of the posts I linked above wrote libraries for it, [NamedType](https://github.com/joboccara/namedtype) and [type_safe](https://github.com/foonathan/type_safe). If you need something heavier-duty, you should check out [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_units.html). Note that I haven't used any of these myself; they're just where I'd check if I needed those features.

You didn't ask about this, but none of this should have any runtime performance costs over just using `float` everywhere and keeping track of units manually, but might make compilation slower.

Comment: thank you @Daniel. I also was thinking about using a library instead of writing it from scratch since it seems unavoidable to use class for type safe

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to create a class for each kind of measurement and implement ways to convert one to another.  The classes could/should have a common superclass.

Comment: as I mentioned, it's cumbersome to repeat all the basic number operators and not yet account for the overhead possibly added

Comment: It doesn't take that long to write the operators, and if you think this is a problem like the OP does it would probably be worth it.

Comment: besides the operators +,-,*,/ there are numerous others to add if I write a class. Am I right? printing <<, casting? is it this obvious need so lengthy work to resolve?

Comment: could you elaborate more on your answer? I tried the OP's struct but it seems still buggy in his example. I don't get what he meant with "template<typename Unit>", he's not using it

Answer (score 2):

I would pick one as internal representation (e.g. Radian) and write other as wrapper classes

```
typedef double Radian;
class Degree {
public:
    Degree() {
        m_radian = 0.0;
    }
    Degree(double degree) {
        m_radian = degree / 180.0 * 3.1415926;
    }
    void operator = (double degree) {
        m_radian = degree / 180.0 * 3.1415926;
    }
    operator Radian() const { return m_radian; }
private:
    Radian m_radian;
};

void print_rad(Radian rad) {
   printf("rad: %lf\n", rad);
}

int main() {
   Radian rad = 123.0;
   Degree degree = 456.0;
   print_rad(rad);
   print_rad(degree);
   print_rad(rad + degree);
   return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

```
rad: 123.000000
rad: 7.958701
rad: 130.958701
```

Comment: how about several numerical operators +-*/, printing, type cast? one will have to write all?

Comment: Radian is type alias to double and everything should be automatically usable, unless you want a different behavior then you can write a more complex Radian class rather than typedef.

Comment: still it does not avoid type mixing when I mix double, Radian or Degree. The compiler does not create error for operations like double a = Radian + 3.3; or even Radian c = rad + degree;

Comment: If you want to denial the use of double, you need to make `Radian` a class as well, and yes you need to write the operators, but its trival and only needed to do once on `Radian` class. `Degree` will remain simple.

Comment: In our productive S/W, we solved it similar. In our case, I made conversion operators `explicit`. The values don't get better if you mix too much deg. and rad. (I mean rounding errors. Pi is such a number...)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a bit flawed, I think.

What you trying to model are physical quantities - types that have a value and a unit.

There is no quantity called a radian. There is a quantity called angle whose units may be radians or degrees.

What you need to is a bit of infrastructure to deal with converting units of quantities and performing operations on units as well as the values.

For example,

```
L1 = 10 "m" (length)
L2 = 20 "m" (length)

L1 * L2 = 200 "m^2" (area)

F1 = 10 "N" (force)
A1 = 2 "m^2" (area)
F1/A1  = 5 "Pa" (pressure)

A2 = 10 "deg"
convert(A2, "rad") = 0.174533 "rad"
```

If you are able to add the code for dealing with units, rest of the functionality will be easy.

We have had to do that at my work and the amount of code is non-trivial. It does not make sense for me delver further into that subject here.

---

Potential C++ code:

```
struct Quantity
{
   double value;
   std::string unit;
};

// Defines operations on Quantity.
Quantity operator+(Quantity const& q1, Quantity const& q2) { ... }
Quantity operator-(Quantity const& q1, Quantity const& q2) { ... }
Quantity operator*(Quantity const& q1, Quantity const& q2) { ... }
Quantity operator*(Quantity const& q1, double f) { ... }
Quantity operator/(Quantity const& q1, Quantity const& q2) { ... }
Quantity operator/(Quantity const& q1, double f) { ... }
Quantity convert(Quantity const& q, std::string const& unit) { ... }

auto L1 = Quantity(10, "m");
auto L2 = Quantity(10, "m");

auto a = L1*L2;  // Resulting in Quantity(100, "m^2")

auto F1 = Quantity(10, "N");
auto A1 = Quantity(2, "m^2");
auto p = F1/A1;  // Resulting in Quantity(5, "Pa")

auto A2 = Quantity(10, "deg");
auto A3 = Convert(A2, "rad");  // Resulting in Quantity(0.174533, "rad")
```

Comment: Is there any way to make that valid C++, or is it meant to be pseudocode? C++ user-defined literals usually use `10_m`, not `10 "m"`, but you'd need to define each power individually.

Comment: @DanielH, that is not even pseudo code. It's conceptual - description of the data the objects hold and the operations one would expect to be supported on those objects.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was reading those as `==` signs, in which case all the lines could be regular code if you declared the variables above and used standard literal syntax. If there were some way to get C++ to accept an integer literal next to a string literal (which I don't know of, outside a macro), and if my misreading were actually what you wrote, it could have been real checks. That's why I asked.

Comment: @DanielH, I updated the answer to use potential C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably want to go the whole way with calculating with units.

Do something like this, with all relevant (SI?) base-units:

```
template <class T, int meter, int second, int pow_10, int pow_deginrad>
class unit {
    T num = 0;
};
// add convenience typedefs. Also look into `operator ""` for denoting literals.
```

Now you *only* have to define arithmetic between the types and magnitudes in one place.
Happy coding.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend sticking to SI bases. SI decided that angles are dimensionless, which works mathematically but for type safety (and this particular example) you might want to keep them separate.

Comment: Sure, that's a valid reason to decide on declaring the unit of angles to be radians (not degrees, because the math works out better that way). One just has to be aware of it when writing formulas down.