# is it possible to refer to child class in parent class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

This is a follow-up post of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124180/use-typedef-for-more-type-safe-in-c?noredirect=1#comment83227450_48124180)

I create two classes RadAngle and DegAngle, the later inherited from the former. Since I want to avoid code repeating, I make DegAngle inherited from RadAngle.

Noting that in RadAngle, I want to make

```
class RadAngle {
...
RadAngle toRad(const DegAngle& dang) {.. do something..}  // <-- child class reference
...
}
```

Is this possible? if not, it's inevitable to rewrite two classes with almost same code?

EDIT01: 
this is now my revised code which does not use two classes but one class instead and empty structs. However, I think it will create other problems in toRad, toDeg to check whether the input type is consistent. It's future work though :P

```
template<typename Unit, typename numT>
class Angle {
public:
    Angle() {
      AngVal = 0.0;
    }
    Angle(const numT& angV) {
      AngVal = angV;
    }
    void operator = (const Angle<Unit,numT>& ang1) {
      AngVal = ang1.getVal();
    }
    Angle operator+(const Angle<Unit,numT>& ang1) const { return Angle<Unit,numT>(AngVal+ang1.getVal()); }
    Angle operator-(const Angle<Unit,numT>& ang1) const { return Angle<Unit,numT>(AngVal-ang1.getVal()); }
    Angle operator*(const Angle<Unit,numT>& ang1) const { return Angle<Unit,numT>(AngVal*ang1.getVal()); }
    Angle operator/(const Angle<Unit,numT>& ang1) const { return Angle<Unit,numT>(AngVal/ang1.getVal()); }

    numT getVal() const { return AngVal;};

    Angle<Unit,numT> toRad(const Angle<Unit,numT>& dang) { return dang.getVal() / 180. * M_PI;}
    Angle<Unit,numT> toDeg(const Angle<Unit,numT>& dang) { return dang.getVal() / M_PI * 180.;}

private:
    numT AngVal;
};

struct Radian;
struct Degree;

int main() {

   Angle<Radian,float> a(1.5);
   Angle<Radian,float> b(3.5);
   Angle<Radian,float> c = a+b;

   //std::cout << c << std::endl;
   printf("%.2f\n",c.getVal());

   Angle<Degree,float> d(45.);

   Angle<Degree,float> z = d + Angle<Degree,float>(15.);
   printf("%.2f\n",z.getVal());


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/243162/271425 doesn't answer your question?

Comment: Is "angle measured in degrees" really a special kind of "angle measured in radians"? Read the links in the answer you accepted.

Comment: @PasserBy for the type safe problem, I've already used a class RadAngle for it. I am considering it small size and quickly developed for my usage. So, I proceed this approach instead of others. I've already provided the RadAngle class in the last post, but when I continued with the DegAngle class, I met the error in the current post. My main purpose is type safe without adding much more code to current program

Comment: @molbdnilo, I want to avoid mixing operations of  Degree & Radian & float/double types in my code  which is the bug I am fixing now

Comment: @ShawnLe I didn't understand what you just said. Isn't the whole point here just to strongly retype a number? The linked post does that exactly, without any boilerplate you seem to imply there is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write two classes with the same code, you can use a class template and let the compiler "write" the code for you.

Somehing like this:

```
template<typename Unit>
struct Angle
{
    // Member functions ...
    float magnitude;
};

struct Deg;
struct Rad;

using RadAngle = Angle<Rad>;
using DegAngle = Angle<Deg>;

RadAngle toRadians(const DegAngle& inDegrees)
{
    // ...
}

DegAngle toDegrees(const RadAngle& inRadians)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you, molbdnilo! this is the approach I prefer. I don't need to revise much my current code and it works charmingly. Are these empty structs also referred to as phantom types?