# Is it possible to create a new primitive type in C++ for embedded platforms?

Tags: c++, embedded, avr, avr-gcc, atmega

I'm writing my own c++ library for an Atmel ATmega2560 chip from scratch as an exercise to learn how it (and electronics in general) works. As part of this, I want to create a new, fundamental `byte` type in C++, that isn't just an alias of another type, and has an exact size of 8 bits.

As this is an embedded platform, I want to avoid generating additional instructions for the chip to process as much as possible, which makes classes and structs a poor fit. I know that I could use the `char` type, but it's size is vaguely defined ("at least one byte", and the size of a byte can vary between platforms) by the C++ standards, and I'm not sure how the AVR platform treats it; though I suspect an `unsigned char` would be 8 bits, as the majority of the registers are 8 bits. There are also other reasons I'd prefer not to use `unsigned char`.

Essentially, what I would like to do once my library is operational is something like:

```
int main()
{
/* PORTB is global object instantiated in my lib that unifies handling the Data Register and Data Direction Register for PORTB pins on the chip. PORTD is similar, just memory addresses of registers are different */
  PORTB.setDDR(0); // All pins are inputs.
  PORTD.setDDR(0xFF); // All pins are outputs.
  byte b = PORTB.read();
  b |= 0b10011000;
  PORTD.write(b);

  return 0;
}
```

Being able to implicitly cast to/from an int and other fundamental types would be a bonus, but probably not necessary. Is it at all possible to do this, short of forking avr-gcc and writing in a new intrinsic type?

Note: I do have the full data sheet for the ATmega2560, which includes a listing of the instruction set. I'm not afraid to use in-line Assembly if I have to, but would prefer not to for performance (after all, I'm only human) and best-practices reasons.

I was able to find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572420/creating-a-new-primitive-type), but that's still just aliasing, and offers no control over the actual size of the type. Some of the answers also mention using a Boost lib; I'm not sure Boost works on AVR, and I don't want to rely on other libraries, as that defeats the purpose of writing my own from scratch.

Comment: "size [of `char`] is vaguely defined", no, it's exactly 1 byte, regardless of platform. Perhaps you're thinking of octet. If so, check out <stdint.h>.

Comment: Unless you are writing your own compiler, you don't need to worry about any of this, your compiler vendor already got it working.

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to program AVR in C++. Due to the external Harvard Architecture this will add quite some overhead (not to speak of Flash and possibly RAM overhead). For the types: read about `stdint.h`. There you have alread properly sized types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. All types in C++ are either defined by the standard ("primitive types", but also pointers and functions), extended types defined by the implementation (`__int128`) or User-Defined Types (classes, structs, unions).

Comment: This begs the question by excluding user-defined types. No type in C or C++ is "just an alias of another type;" `typedef` implements aliases but does not create types.

Answer (score 0):

An enumeration with fixed underlying type can fit your requirements:

```
enum byte : unsigned char {};
```

However, your conceptual foundations seem a bit shaky:

> and I'm not sure how the AVR platform treats it

In embedded programming, you generally spend more time learning about the particular platform. It's a safe bet that `char` is exactly eight bits on an 8-bit platform, but really you should find the manual that actually says so.

> /* PORTB is global object instantiated in my lib that unifies handling the Data Register and Data Direction Register for PORTB pins on the chip. PORTD is similar, just memory addresses of registers are different */

This is not a job for your library to do. The chip vendor usually knows best when it comes to their own hardware and the compilers they support. Use the official libraries.

It can be a fun exercise to build your own runtime library using the compiler as a foundation, but you don't really want to develop and support this in perpetuity.

Comment: Correct me, if I'm wrong, but IIRC, an `enum` in C++ would only allow to be assigned its constants as defined. So you can't combine bits, etc. as you can do in C (where you can't specify the underlying type otoh. You actually would have to provide constants for all possible values.

Comment: @Olaf No, C++ enumerations are backward-compatible with C. The C++ standard even blesses enumerations by allowing them to implement bitset types in `std::`.

Comment: Hmm... I actually was pretty sure that is one of the major differences. I really need to refresh my C++ knowledge.

Comment: I'm down voting this answer because it completely missed the fact that I'm doing this for fun and education. I know that for an real application, I'd be better off using avr-libc and C. I also explicitly stated that I did not want to use an pre-made library, so telling me to just use the official libraries is counter productive. Further, I never indicated that I was going to release this library. It's just an learning exercise. Finally, I do have the full data sheet for the chip. I even said so. But it's over 1k pages long, and I learn best by doing, which is the whole point of this exercise

Comment: @KDØBPV It's your prerogative, but none of your criticisms apply to the solution here, which is to use an enumeration. (The data sheet may not say anything about the C ABI, most don't.) For what it's worth, I'm the only one who upvoted your question.

Comment: Also, saying "There are also other reasons I'd prefer not to use unsigned char" makes it sound like more than "fun and education."